# Is there an appropriate way to dynamically generate secrets for docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file that has a DB and a django application

It looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
#    This is the bad part that I don't I need to change
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypass
  web:
    environment:
      - DB=postgres
      - DB_USER=user
      - DB_PASSWORD=mypass
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

and in my settings.py I'm doing

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

But the problem with this is that the secrets are.... well exposed. Is it possible to have docker build dynamically construct a secret that you can persistently pass to your application even after restarts?

Comment: You could use secrets if you start using swarm.

Comment: @snahor I'll have to look into swarm!